# Map inherited class using custom converter dozer

Tags: java, inheritance, dozer

I have the below classes and the custom converters for these classes

```
public class A {

    public A() {}
}

public class B extends A {

    public B() {}
}
```

Convertors using dozer version 5.2.0.

```
<converter type="ADozerConvertor">
    <class-a>A</class-a>
    <class-b>C</class-b>
</converter>
<converter type="BDozerConvertor">
        <class-a>B</class-a>
        <class-b>C</class-b>
</converter>
```

If I try to map B to C. It doens't call BDozerConvertor and call ADozerConvertor.